Transformation of a complex function into a real function via Euler's formula?
I am new as a member but I'll try my best to make it as understandable and easy to follow as possible. I recently had to find a general solution to this homogeneous differential equation:
\begin{equation}
y'''(x) + 3y''(x) + 2.5y'(x) = 0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
via Euler's method I arrived at the characteristic polynomial:
\begin{equation}
\chi(x) = \lambda^3 + 3\lambda^2 + 2.5\lambda = \lambda (\lambda^2 + 3\lambda + 2.5) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
The solutions to the polynomial are:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_0 = 0, \lambda_{1,2} = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{9-10}}{2} = -\frac{3}{2} \pm \frac{i}{2} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
So far so good. By Euler's method one gets:
\begin{equation}
y(x) = A + B\cdot e^{-\frac{3+i}{2}x} + C\cdot e^{-\frac{3-i}{2}x}\tag{4} \quad A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
Finally my question: In the solution our professor gave the result is in its trigonometric form, which I understand is achieved though Euler's formula $e^{ix} = i \cdot \sin x + \cos x $. However I do not get why there is no imaginary unit i in there anymore. I have come across this already numerous times, where the trigonometric form of a complex number was somehow transformed into a term with real elements only. Is there a mathematical reason or a version of Euler's formula that allows this or why can the imaginary unit be left out?
The correct solution is:
\begin{equation}
y(x) = A + B \cdot e^{-\frac{3x}{2}}\sin(\frac{x}{2}) + C \cdot e^{-\frac{3x}{2}} \cos(\frac{x}{2}) \quad A,B,C \in \mathbb{R} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
I would have expected the same form but with an i before the sin term or the constants B and C to be in the complex set $\mathbb{C}$ and that they somehow "absorbed" the i. What is happening here? (and why?)
I really hope I could present my question well and streamlined. Thank you for your inputs in advance!

Are your boundary or initial values complex?

There were no boundaries or initial values, because it was not stated as an initial value problem, but just an ordinary differential equation. The task was to find the general solution.

Then you found it. If there's an assumption the solution is real, take the real part of what you found.

Arbitrary constants are, well, arbitrary so they can absorb any constants they want. $i$ is just another constant. But more specifically the $A,B,C$ in the first solution are not the same as the $A,B,C$ in the second solution. They are related by $$\begin{cases}A_2=A_1\B_2=-iB_1+iC_1\C_2=B_1+C_1\end{cases}$$

Any multiple, including complex multiples, of one of the arbitrary constants as as good as any other in terms of a general solution. For some problems you want to absorb the imaginary unit into the coefficient, sometimes you want to make it more explicit. I've only encountered keeping the complex exponential when I was solving an equation at a boundary. For example, in quantum mechanics, you usually want to keep the function and first derivative to remain constant even if the differential equation itself is different on both sides of the boundary.

Since the coefficients are real, if $y$ is a solution, so is $\bar{y}$. Since the equation is linear, this means that $y+\bar{y}$ is a solution and so is $i(y-\bar{y})$, both of which are real. This is where the trigonometric form of solution comes from.

This is actually subtle and not well-explained in introductory differential equations courses that I've seen. To say it with a minimum of technical detail, when the roots of the characteristic polynomial are complex, Euler's method actually tells you the complex solutions of the differential equation (in other words we consider differentiable functions $y : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ - it is not necessary to make $x$ complex, only $y$). But ultimately what we want is to figure out the real solutions. So what we need to do is to figure out which of the functions of the form
$$y(x) = A + B e^{-\frac{3+i}{2}x} + C e^{-\frac{3-i}{2}x}\tag{4} \quad A,B,C \in \mathbb{C}$$
(note that $A, B, C \in \mathbb{C}$ now) are real. We do this by rewriting the complex exponential in terms of its real and imaginary parts, which lets us rewrite the general complex solution as
$$y(x) = A' + B' e^{-\frac{3}{2} x} \cos \frac{x}{2} + C' e^{-\frac{3}{2} x} \sin \frac{x}{2} \quad A', B', C' \in \mathbb{C}$$
where $A', B', C' \in \mathbb{C}$ are now a different set of arbitrary complex constants; more precisely we have $A' = A, B' = B + C, C' = i (B - C)$. Now we want to know when a function in this form is real, and now it's a little more obvious: $A', B'$, and $C'$ must all be real (this actually requires a small argument to see but hopefully it is at least intuitive). So the general real solution is
$$y(x) = A' + B'  e^{-\frac{3}{2} x} \cos \frac{x}{2} + C' e^{-\frac{3}{2} x} \sin \frac{x}{2} \quad A', B', C' \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Note a subtlety that requiring $B', C'$ to be real does not correspond to requiring $B, C$ to be real, and imposes some more complicated constraints on the real and imaginary parts of $B, C$ instead.
To say all this more conceptually requires diving into some linear algebra, more precisely the concepts of bases, eigenvectors, and complexification. Really linear algebra and differential equations should be taught simultaneously, neither is complete as a subject without the other.
